# How to set and use an Oracle Connection attribute

Tags: java, oracle11g, triggers

I have a db trigger and I would like that in a certain connection he will not do his insert/update/delete.

I thought about using an attribute value in his plsql code that indicates whether this connection his from this certain kind. I want to set this attribute of the connection in java. How can I do this? And if it can't be done, I am open for other suggestion of how to make the trigger to don't do his logic in some of the connections (depends of what the connection purposes are).

Edited:

Thanks guys I think I have a different solution for my problem. actually I have a field in the row that I insert (that fires the trigger) which help me indicate whether the trigger should fire or not.

Comment: what you have tried>>

Comment: I just don't know how to implement this.

Comment: How do you distinguish between connections? Different users? contexts?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to use [`dbms_application_info`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS65237) to pass a value to the `client_info`.

In your Java program do:

```
cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{call dbms_application_info.set_client_info(?)}");
cstmt.setString(1, "no_triggers");
cstmt.execute();
```

Then in your trigger you can do something like this:

```
create or replace trigger ...
as
declare
  l_info varchar(65);
begin
  dbms_application_info.read_client_info(l_info);
  if l_info = 'no_triggers' then
    return;
  end if;

  ... actual trigger code follows here

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a custom trigger for user access control, because it can easily become a maintenance nightmare. Instead, create a dedicated [`ROLE` or `PROFILE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admusers.htm#i1007119) which is only `GRANT`ed `SELECT` on that table and which you use for your "special" connection.